# How to create a scrollable modal bottomsheet

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create mobal bottomsheet in flutter. Bottomsheet will be half visible and when the user lifts it up, it will open up to the specified size.

I searched but couldn't find what I wanted. How can I do this without using a plugin

[image]

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DraggableScrollableSheet instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,`bottom_sheet` for more [here](https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_sheet)

There is `showStickyFlexibleBottomSheet` that you can use like this.

```
showStickyFlexibleBottomSheet(
  minHeight: 0,
  initHeight: 0.5,
  maxHeight: 1,
  headerHeight: 200,
  context: context,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, double offset) {
    return Container(
      ...
    );
  },
  builder: (BuildContext context, double offset) {
    return SliverChildListDelegate(
      <Widget>[...],
    );
  },
  anchors: [0, 0.5, 1],
);
```

Comment: for more explanation visit the link